# How to handle progress bar when loading images in a list

Tags: c#, image, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-8

I am creating a windows phone application where am i displayed `movie list in a ListBox`.
And `Image control` in the list item template is binding to the Movie `image url address` so that movie images are displaying in the tile.

But there is some time lag for loading and displaying the images in each tile since it come from the image url using internet. So i decided to display a Progress bar till the image loads.

**See my class structure and xaml**

```
Public class Movie
{
  Public string MovieName{get;set;}
  Public string MovieImageUrl{get;set;}
} 

private List<Movie> _movieList;
Public  List<Movie> MovieList
{
  get{return _movieList;}
  set 
     {
      _movieList=value;
      RaiseProperty("MovieList");
     }
}
```

**xaml :**

```
 <ListBox ItemSource={Binding MovieList}>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Height="200" Width="150">
                  <ProgressBar IsIndeterminate="True"></ProgressBar>
                  <Image Source="{Binding MovieImageUrl}"/>
                  <TextBlock Text="{Binding MovieName}"></TextBlock>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
   </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

In this implementation progressbar will not be visible after image loads, but it is continue to run under the image. I want to stop the progressbar running after image loaded in each tile.

I know how to handle this if there is only one image by stopping the progress bar  in the `Image Loaded` event. But  this case i am quite unsure about it.

Can anybody help me to do the thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Handel Loaded event of image and try this.

Xaml

```
 <ListBox ItemSource={Binding MovieList}>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Height="200" Width="150">
              <ProgressBar IsIndeterminate="True"></ProgressBar>
              <Image Source="{Binding MovieImageUrl}" Loaded="Image_Loaded"/>
              <TextBlock Text="{Binding MovieName}"></TextBlock>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
   </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Xaml.cs

```
  private void Image_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Image img = sender as Image;
        ((ProgressBar)((Grid)img.Parent).Children[0]).IsIndeterminate = false;
    }
```

above image loaded event will be fired for every images in the list(after the images is loaded) and in the code I am getting the reference of the progress bar in the list item and setting its IsIndeterminage property to false to stop the progressbar animation.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I know this solution . Am asking for handling the same with a list of images.

Comment: "By list of images" I did not understand.... if you mean images in the listbox as in the above example than above solution will fine. bcz for every image loaded event in the listbox this loaded event will be fired and in the event handler code I am getting parent of Imange as grid....

Comment: so we can't put list template in to the resource dictionary . right? or have to handle it in the view itself. Thanks